# Expresso Store: 2Checkout gives Invalid key error

Tags: expresso-store, payment-gateway

i have a problem with 2checkout gateway. I get "Invalid key" error. What is causing that?
I entered correctly the Account number and secret word in settings. Test mode is "false" in Store settings. Demo setting is "On" in 2co settings page.

No matter witch setting i try:

[image]

i get Invalid key error.

I have EE 2.7.1, Store 2.0.6, PHP 5.3.27

Thanks

Comment: Can you email support@exp-resso.com about this? We will most likely need to access your server to diagnose this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is most likely being caused by either your secret word not matching or expresso store is not setup to validate the hash on demo sales. When placing 2Checkout demo sales, the MD5 hash returned by 2Checkout is intentionally broken by computing the hash with a 1 in place of the order_number so if you are checking against the hash your return script needs to handle this change.

Example:

```
<?php

if ($_REQUEST['demo'] == 'Y') 
{
    $order_number = 1;
}
else
{
    $order_number = $_REQUEST['order_number'];
}

$compare_string = $_REQUEST['secret_word'] . $_REQUEST['sid'] . $order_number . $_REQUEST['total'];
$compare_hash1 = strtoupper(md5($compare_string));
$compare_hash2 = $_REQUEST['key'];

if ($compare_hash1 != $compare_hash2)
{
    echo "Hash Mismatch";
}
else
{
    echo "Hash Matched";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I checked and Store does handle the strange test mode order_number exception. So in that case the only explanation is that the secret key must be wrong. See https://github.com/omnipay/2checkout/blob/master/src/Omnipay/TwoCheckout/Message/CompletePurchaseRequest.php#L16